# Making sense of the derivatives of $|Ax-b|^2$ in Least Square Fitting from Calculus

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, maxima-minima, least-squares

> The partial derivatives of $|Ax|^2$ with respect to $x_1, ... , x_n$ fill the vector $2A^T Ax$.
> The derivatives of $2b^T Ax$ fill the vector $2A^T b$. So the derivatives of $|Ax-b|^2$ are
> zero when __________________

From the least square fitting I understand that derivatives of $|Ax-b|^2$ are
zero when $A^TAx=A^Tb$ where the idea is to minimise errors. But, how do I make sense of the first two statements in the given question:

"The partial derivatives of $|Ax|^2$ with respect to $x_1, ... , x_n$ fill the vector $2A^T Ax$" and "The derivatives of $2b^T Ax$ fill the vector $2A^T b$" ?

$$
|Ax-b|^2=(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)=(x^TA^T-b^T)(AX-b)\\=x^TA^TAx-x^TA^Tb-b^TAx-b^Tb\\
=|Ax|^2-b^TAx-(b^TAx)^T-|b|^2
$$

**Reference:** 24, 4.3, Chapter 4 : Orthogonality, Introduction to Linear Algebra, Gilbert Strang

Comment: $x^TA^TAx$ is a multivariate function with $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ as varoables. Now unleash some calculus tools to evaluate partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the problem here is to minimize the function $f = \| Ax -b\|^2$, which can be written as

$$ \min_{x} \| Ax -b\|^2 $$

The minimum value of $f$ is reached at $\hat{x}$, which is also the point for which the gradient (the first derivative) of $f$ w.r.t to $x$ equals to zero, that is:

$$ \frac{\partial \| Ax -b\|^2}{\partial x} = 0$$

For simplicity, we use the Frobenius product notation, and then we differentiate w.r.t $x$

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y & = Ax-b \\
dy & = Adx \\
f & = \|y\|^2 \\
  & = y:y \\
df & = dy:y + y:dy  \\ 
  & = 2y:dy \\
  & = 2y:Adx \\
  & = 2A^Ty:dx \\
\frac{df}{dx} & = 2A^Ty\\
& = 2A^T(Ax -b)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now, we set the derivative equal to zero

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{df}{dx} & = 0 \\
2A^T(Ax -b) & = 0\\
2A^TAx - 2A^Tb & = 0 \\
\implies 2A^TAx & = 2A^Tb \\
\implies \hat{x} & = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb \\ 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: No comment ! Did this answer your question ?